# Domain points me to some malicious URL and I can't get rid of it

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, domain, redirect, malicious

Whenever I enter my URL into the browser, it keeps pointing me to

```
http://fornax.myvnc.com/dev
```

The URL doesn't even work and my antivirus doesn't complain about it so I am not sure what is happening. I logged into my domain manager at godaddy and it says that the nameservers are pointing to:

```
NS46.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

and I am not sure where this came from either because my hosting is with lunarpages whose nameserver is

```
NS1.LUNARMANIA.COM
```

I tried looking into my .htaccess and it is blank. My index.php was hijacked with some malicious code so I removed it completely. Everything is supposed to be normal now but still some kind of a redirection is taking place and am not sure where this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell us what your domain is so we can troubleshoot for you?

Comment: @Scott: Issues got resolved so removed the URL from here... Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have fixed this?

```
<html>
<head>

<META   HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
        Content = "1;
        URL=http://www.lunarpages.com"

</head>    
</html>
```

I loaded this is an telnet session so there was no refresh, but if your IP address is 67.210.98.60, then you are no longer redirecting people to a bad site.  If your IP address is not 67.210.98.60, then your DNS has been hacked.

Running an nslookup from here, I don't see that your nameserver is domaincontrol.com.  Did you let your domain expire?  I have seen a domain get parked when it expires.

On another note, maybe these [guys](http://isc.sans.org/diary.html?storyid=5146&rss) are at it again.  You might call GoDaddy and double check.

Comment: Just tried it from a different computer and it works. Turns out that it was just on this computer... Thanks for the help... Marked as answer because of the link you provided.

Comment: Also, for anyone else looking for a solution, Scott was right... My DNS was hacked someone though I have no clue as to how this could have happened...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new simple index.php page with basic information in it... ie. hello world.  See if you still get redirected.  This will at least narrow down what could be causing the problem.

It's probable that there is still some code hidden in the index.php page redirecting you, or, some dodgy iframe link.  Check for iframes and base64_decode entries in the current index.php.

Comment: Thanks... I created a new file and it still redirects. This puzzles me even more! And also, I checked the old index.php and removed all the base64 entries... I actually replaced it with the index.php from the original package of the web application...